# Quisiera hacer un crud e inicio de sesion con Angular y necesito ayuda con el controlador

Tags: angular

```
var angular;
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard', { templateUrl: 'template/books.html', controller: 'CustomerListControler' })

    .when('/NewCustomer', { templateUrl: 'template/formNew.html', controller: 'CustomerAddControler' })

    .when('/UpdateCustomer/:id', { templateUrl: 'template/form.html', controller: 'CustomerEditControler' })

    .when('/entrar', { templateUrl: 'template/entrar.html', controller: 'EntrarControler' })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/dashboard' });
}]);

app.controller('CustomerListControler', [
  '$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('api/Customers').success(function(data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
      });
  }
]),

  app.controller('EntrarControler', [
  '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

      $scope.master = {};
      $scope.activePath = null;


      $scope.New_Customer = function(customer, AddNewForm) {
        console.log(customer);

        $http.post('api/entrar', customer).success(function() {
          $scope.reset();
          $scope.activePath = $location.path('/dashboard');
        });
        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.customer = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };
        $scope.reset();
      }
  }
]),

  app.controller('CustomerAddControler', [
  '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

      $scope.master = {};
      $scope.activePath = null;

      $scope.New_Customer = function(customer, AddNewForm) {
        console.log(customer);

        var data_name = $routeParams.data_name;
        if (data_name == true) {
          $http.get('api/Book/' + data_name).success(function() {
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/NewCustomer');
          });
          $scope.mymensaje = "datos encontrado";
        }
        else {

          $http.post('api/New_Customer', customer).success(function() {
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/dashboard');
          });
          $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.customer = angular.copy($scope.master);
          };
          $scope.reset();
          alert('datos agregados');
        }
      }
  }
]),

  app.controller('CustomerEditControler', [

  '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

      var id = $routeParams.id;

      $scope.activePath = null;

      $http.get('api/Customers/' + id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.CustomerDetail = data;
      });

      $scope.Update_Customer = function(customer) {
        var updateCustomer = confirm('desea modificar los datos de: ' + id);
        if (updateCustomer) {
          $http.put('api/Customers/' + id, customer).success(function(data) {
            $scope.CustomerDetail = data;
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/dashboard');
          });
        }
        $scope.mensaje = "datos actualizados";
      }

      $scope.Delete_Customer = function(customer) {
        console.log(customer);
        var deleteCustomer = confirm('estais seguro querer borrar registro?' + id);
        if (deleteCustomer) {
          $http.delete('api/Customers/' + customer.id);
          $scope.activePath = $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
      };

  }
]);
```

Comment: y cual es el error que exactamente tienes? sería muy buena idea que no solo pongas el código sino que detalles exactamente lo que no logras que ocurra

Comment: quiero hacer como un condicional que al momento de registrar, me verifique si el nombre de dato se encuentra registrado. Podrias ayudarme? usando este controlador